# Transfer text file to csv format Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a "|" separated data file. Need to transfer it to csv format.
In csv I have 9 columns. And the data is in format:

```
257|30|1666|4906|3712|1|1.00|4.99|1.04|2|27.28|2.00|4.92|1|4.99|1.00|1.04|9|0.222222|0.000000|0.111111|-1.000000
254|1|1578|3713|4900|1|1.00|1.99|1.26|16|53.30|25.00|12.23|39|125.30|55.00|62.48|320|0.050000|0.000000|0.003125|0.000000
256|38|227|25303|25306|1|1.00|11.99|1.99|1|6.99|1.00|1.67|7|62.28|9.00|9.08|16|0.062500|1.000000|0.062500|0.000000
```

is there a built functions? What do you advise to use?
Thanks

Comment: read the file content to a string, replace the pipes by commas and write the string back to a file. That's three lines of code...

Comment: You can simply use the String `split` and `join` methods. With Java 8 it's even more easier.

Comment: Have a look at this question for splitting. Once you get array, you can store it in CSV file using File IO. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219776/scanning-a-txt-file-and-creating-an-array-out-of-strings-in-this-case-vending/33220268#33220268

Comment: What's the character encoding of your file?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an inputstream to read from your data file and replace every occurrence of the pipe symbol with a comma and you use an output stream to write back you will be a happy man. you can use every 9th pipe as some sort signal to move your output to a new line. That's like 10 lines of code